# Do you know an MVC framework for Win32 Delphi applications?

Tags: delphi, model-view-controller

As far as I know, there isn't.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need a framework? MVC is just a pattern. You can look it up and implement it directly. I would suggest however that you implement MVP instead of MVC. MVP is a more modern variation of MVC that fits in better with environments such as Windows where the View does user input and output. (Unlike in MVC where the View only does output, and the Controller only does input.)

Answer (score 4):

Look at this [implementation](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Foszhdl.be.schule.de%2Fgymnasium%2Ffaecher%2Finformatik%2Fdelphi%2Fmvc.htm&sl=de&tl=en).

Comment: wow this seems to be a bug with SO, I can see 'look at this implementation' with implementation hyperlinked clearly in preview but apparently it dos not display it right, neways I had to translate it to english and the link is 

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://oszhdl.be.schule.de/gymnasium/faecher/informatik/delphi/mvc.htm&ei=mj76Sc0risgyrcHJzA4&sa=X&oi=translate&resnum=1&ct=result&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://oszhdl.be.schule.de/gymnasium/faecher/informatik/delphi/mvc.htm%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26rls%3Dcom.microsoft:en-us

Comment: Yup, seems to be a markdown bug alright. I simplified the Google Translate URL, should work now.

Answer (score 3):

A little different, but you can see the a MVP implementation here:

http://jazz-sdk.googlecode.com

Answer (score 3):

There is a model-gui-mediator framework available with the ti Object Persistence Framework.

MGM is similar to MVC.  Graeme Geldenhuys has an article describing it at http://opensoft.homeip.net/articles/.

AFAIAA the MGM framework requires the use of tiOPF (not a bad thing, but it can make it harder to learn) but it should still demonstrate the basic concepts.

tiOPF is available at tiOPF.com.  If you are interested, get the code from the repository as it is more up to date.  There is a D2009 branch in the repository as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old article, but here's another option: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=53  Look for: eMVC v.1.0